# If else condition in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have to display a list of element in groups. I am expecting out like in the image.

[image]

If I remove `if` condition its printing all option in all groups.

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{menuView.menunames}" var="name">
            <p:tab title="#{name}">
                <c:forEach items="#{menuView.menu}" var="entry">

                <h:outputText value="(#{entry.key} == #{name})"></h:outputText>
                    <c:if test='#{entry.key} == #{name}'>
                        <h:dataTable value="#{entry.value}" var="submenu">
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{submenu}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>

  private Map<String, List<String>> menu;
  private List<String> menunames;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EL expression should be like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{entry.key == name}">
<c:if test="#{entry.key eq name}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a `c:choose` for this, with the `c:when` for the `if` part and `c:otherwise` for the `else` part.